# Java - Polymorphism : legal vs illegal declarations

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

```
                                      ANIMAL
                                  /           \
                      VERTEBRATE             INVERTEBRATE
                     /     |     \           /     |     \
                   CAT    DOG    COW      SPIDER  ANT   CORAL
                  /   \
          COLOR_SOLID CALICO
```

Animal is the parent class and the rest are subclasses

Polymorphically, I understand that it is legal to declare this:

```
Animal donkey = new Vertebrate();
```

But it is illegal to declare:

```
Invertebrate starfish = new Cat();
```

Or:

```
Spider red = new Invertebrate();
```

My main concerns are:

How can I identify legal vs illegal declarations?

Is it safe to assume this: while the child can inherit from the parent, the parent cannot inherit from the child?

Comment: _How can I identify legal vs illegal declarations?_ what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: In some totalitarian countries, you can get 5-10 years in prison for illegal declarations.

Comment: @Aominè _How can I identify legal vs illegal declarations?_ : Something that will cause an error, problem, etc.

Comment: If you rotate your class hierarchy diagram 90 degrees counter-clockwise, you basically get all the valid assignments. `Animal = Vertibrate`, `Vertibrate = Cat`, `Cat = Calico`, etc. All the other assignments are invalid.

Comment: You can also declare an Animal kitty = new Cat();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.

```
Invertebrate starfish = new Cat();
```

is not allowed because `Cat` does not implement the `Invertebrate` class and it is not a descendant of anything that implements it.

```
Spider red = new Invertebrate();
```

is not allowed because `Invertebrate` is not a descendant of `Spider`.

You can think of this by analogy with the real world using the standard "IS A" terminology.

A `Spider` IS AN `Invertebrate`.

An `Invertebrate` IS NOT A `Spider` (there are invertebrates that are not spiders).

A `Cat` IS NOT AN `Invertebrate` (though, you can put both of them in a box).

Extra:

The "put both of them in a box" demonstrates a separate concept, that of an *Interface*. You can create the interface `Boxable` and then edit the `Cat` and `Invertebrate` classes so that they implement that interface. *No relationship is required between the classes that implement the interface*. This allows you to treat classes that are distant cousins in their class hierarchies as interchangeable *when it makes sense to do so*.